# Problem regarding open cv graphing

Tags: opencv

I want to know that if i want to do graphing in open cv would i have to install seperate library for this purpose or it can be plotted using other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can install opencv from the repository (at least with Ubuntu 12.04 or newer). To get started, the easiest way is probably `sudo apt-get install python-opencv`. If you need or want to use the C instead of Python, `sudo apt-get install libcv-dev`. It does not hurt to have both installed.

I am not sure what other ways of plotting you're thinking, but off the top of my head, at least *gnuplot*, *matplotlib*, *octave*, and *R* have easy plotting capabilities and are available in the default repositories.

Comment: i have previously installed open cv but my problem is behind the fact that after many searches i found that open cv does not come with handy graphing functions. Is it so.

Comment: Then try matplotlib (in Python), it is quite handy. You could also improve the question by stating your goals more precisely, and (hopefully!) receive better answers.